# $this->getLayout()->createBlock(.......) is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, blocks, view

I have added a custom module to magento admin panel, my Controller is as following

```
    <?php
class ABC_Adminhello_AdminhelloController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();

        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhello\adminhtml_export');

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
        $this->_setActiveMenu('sales/order')
                ->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

and My **block** is like this

```
    <?php
class ABC_Adminhello_Block_Adminhtml_Export extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->setTemplate('export/order.phtml');  
  }


}
```

The problem is that in my Controller

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhello\adminhtml_export');
```

returns false, no block is crated, I am unable to find the reason.

Comment: `$this->renderLayout();` remove that

Comment: Try Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhello\adminhtml_export');

Comment: Nothing working, still getLayout()->createBlock('adminhello\adminhtml_export');  returns false

Comment: Is there any other way to load view for module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `indexAction()` function with the below:

```
  public function indexAction() {

    $this->loadLayout();

    $this->_setActiveMenu('sales/order')

    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhello/adminhtml_export'))

    $this->renderLayout();

   }
```

If this does not work, share your `config.xml` so that I can help you further with this.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhello\adminhtml_export');
> ```
>
> returns false, no block is crated, I am unable to find the reason.

That's because you wrote the class alias with a backslash `\` instead of a forward slash `/`.

Besides that you should remove the first call to `renderLayout()` and only call it once **at the end**:

Answer (score 0):

Follow bellow steps

**Step : 1** Create `adminhello.xml` at location `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhello_adminhtml_adminhello_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="adminhello/adminhtml_export" name="export" />
        </reference>
    </adminhello_adminhtml_adminhello_index>
</layout>
```

**Step :2**
Create controller file `AdminhelloController.php` at location `app\code\local\ABC\Adminhello\controllers\Adminhtml\AdminhelloController`

```
<?php
class ABC_Adminhello_Adminhtml_AdminhelloController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction() 
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
             ->_setActiveMenu('sales/order')
             ->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: Both solutions are not working

Comment: Is there any other way to load view for module?

Comment: have you created layout file adminhello.xml at location app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\